# WinJS: Hide scollbars in listview

Tags: winjs

I'm trying to hide the horizontal scrollbars in a WinJS [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211837.aspx) control.  Any ideas?  I will be making an API call that constrains the number of items returns, but if something goes wrong and more items are returned, or an error is returned, I want to make sure the layout doesn't break and horizontal scrollbars appear.  This is a case where I'm floating four listviews side-by-side.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use either the [`-ms-overflow-style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441298.aspx) css property or the `overflow` css property depending upon your desired behavior.

If you want the user to still be able to scroll, even if there are no scroll bars then you should use:

`#listviewid .win-viewport{
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}`

If you don't want the user to be able to scroll, just use:

`#listviewid .win-viewport{
    overflow: hidden;
}`